# How to set a TargetNullValue default for all textboxes in an application?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have an application that I would like to set all the textboxes that use a specific style to have a default binding setting of `TargetNullValue=''` by including it in my style definition for the textboxes.

For example I have a window w/ the following default style set for textboxes

```
<baseTypes:WorkspaceViewBase.Resources>
    ...
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxValidation}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    </Style>
    ...
</baseTypes:WorkspaceViewBase.Resources>
```

And one of the textboxes is currently set up as

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyValue, TargetNullValue=''}" Visibility="{Binding MyVisibility}"/>
```

How can I set the 'TextBoxValidation' style up to include the `TargetNullValue=''` so all the texboxes would include that as the default?

Comment: Create a custom binding type.

Comment: Can I set a custom binding type in my style, so I don't have to change a large amount of textbox types?

Comment: The binding is not related to the Style. See my answer.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of, your answer is almost certainly the correct one.

Comment: Is this even necessary?  The `TextBox.Text` property automatically coerces `null` to `String.Empty`, so a binding that returns `null` should already produce an empty string on the target.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: If I do not set the 'TargetNullValue=''' I get a binding error complaining that it cannot convert '' to the double? it is bound to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom binding type that sets a default value for the `TargetNullValue` property:

```
public class MyBinding : Binding
{
    public MyBinding()
        : base()
    {
        TargetNullValue = string.Empty;
    }

    public MyBinding(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        TargetNullValue = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And replace all `{Binding}` with this one in your XAML markup:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{local:MyBinding MyValue}" Visibility="{Binding MyVisibility}"/>
```

You cannot do this using a `Style` though because the `{Binding}` is not part of nor has anything to do with the `Style`.